# Instance method to preload data in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If I have my model class and want to fetch related data in the same query, I can:

```
instance = Model.includes(:related1, :related2, ...).find 1
```

Or any other alternative, according to my case.

I want to do it in the inverse order:

1. Obtain the instance.
2. **Later**, preload associated data.

Example:

```
instance = Model.find 1
# This is just to make the idea.
instance.preload(:related1, :related2, ...)
```

Is there any instance method like the one I am asking?

Comment: Can;t you try: Model.find(:first, :includes => :association)

Comment: No. There must be separate moments. The first one occurs inside a before_action

Comment: did you get any better solution ?

Comment: No. I ended loading again the same instance. Is not so heavy. But the question is still open: I cannot modify the call to .find()

Comment: You have to metaprogramming the same to modify